# Replace text with regexp

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have to replace text this way:

```
Some data la-la-la [image=test.png] next data...
Some data la-la-la 123 [image=test2.png]
```

And replace that with:

```
Some data la-la-la test.png next data...
Some data la-la-la 123 test2.png
```

I tried with re.sub method from python:

```
for foo in re.search('(\[image=(.*)\])', text):
   text = re.sub("(?<=\[image=)*(?=\])", foo, text)
```

But that won't work, why?

Comment: -1: **Do it for me** question disguised with random nonsense attempts without any effort of reading at least the minimal part of the API

Comment: @nosklo +1 flag for Unnecessary Rudeness.

Comment: @nosklo Yeah, it is. My bad. Not a random attemp :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seriously, did you read [regex documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re) or at least the [howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex)?

- `.search()` returns a match object. You can't iterate over it.
- `.sub()` replaces all occurrences in the string at once. You can't replace one by one.

One idea:

```
import re

text = """Some data la-la-la [image=test.png] next data...
Some data la-la-la 123 [image=test2.png]"""

text = re.sub(r'\[image\=([^\]]+)\]', r'\1', text)

print text
```

the results:

```
Some data la-la-la test.png next data...
Some data la-la-la 123 test2.png
```

Comment: @Ock: this is about how to use Python, not regex.

Comment: Probably, yeah. I just rework some project, not mine. I haven't time to learn Python deeply. Please, help me.

Comment: Seriously, did you read the SO faq? Did you really say RTFM?...On SO?!!...Really?!?!?!?!

Comment: @Ockonal Don't try to win over the haters; you're not the jack-ass whisperer.